# laravel 4 Input::old() is empty

Tags: php, input, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 for a project, but got an issue. I'm not sure, **what i'm doing wrong**.

**Details:**

- Form is posted to the controller's save function.
- When validation fails, i'm redirecting to the create function
- After redirect (using `Redirect::to(somewhere)->withErrors($validator)->withInput()`):

  - Validation errors are being displayed correctly (if any)
  - Input::old() is empty (it should contain previously submitted data)

***Create* function in controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $this->scripts[] = 'various js path here';

    return View::make('admin.modules.events.create', array(
        // Loading various scripts specified in this function
        'scripts' => $this->scripts,
    ));
}
```

**In the view:**

```
...
{{ Form::bsInput('event_name', 'Event title', 'event title goes here', $error = (($errors->has('event_name')) ? $errors->get('event_name') : false), $type = 'text', Input::old('event_name')) }}
...
```

**Note**: `bsInput` is a wrapper around Form::Input() to create bootstrap controls together with labels

**Controller:**

```
public function save()
{

    if (Input::has('submitEventSave'))
    {
        $event = Mihirevent::find(Input::get(event_id));
        $event_add = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $event = new Mihirevent();
        $event_add = true;
    }

    if ($event === false)
    {
        // doing something else
    }
    else
    {

        $event->event_name              = Input::get('event_name');
        $event->event_slug              = Input::get('event_slug');
        $event->event_description       = Input::get('event_description');
        $event->event_location_text     = Input::get('event_location_text');
        $event->event_location_data     = Input::get('event_location_data');
        $event->event_status            = Input::get('event_status');
        $event->featured_image          = Input::get('featured_image');
        $event->event_date_from         = Input::get('event_date_from');
        $event->event_date_until        = Input::get('event_date_until');

        $validation_rules = $event_add === true?$event->rules:$event->update_rules;

        $inputs = array(
            'event_name'            => $event->event_name,
            'event_slug'            => $event->event_slug,
            'event_location_text'   => $event->event_location_text,
        );


        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $validation_rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            Input::flash();
            if ($event_add === true)
            {
                return Redirect::to('admin/event/create')
                           ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::to('admin/event/edit/'.$event->event_id)
                            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }
        }

        // save
        MihirEvent::save();

        // redirect to list 
        return Redirect::route('adminEvent');

    }
}
```

**Update:**

`bsInput` macro:

```
Form::macro('bsInput', function($name, $text, $placeholder = null, $error = false, $type = 'text', $default = null, $class=null)
{
    $label = Form::label($name, $text, array('class' => 'control-label'));
    $input = Form::input($type, $name, $default, array('placeholder' => $placeholder, 'class' => 'form-control'.($class?' '.$class:'')));

    $error_messages = false;
    if($error)
    {
        $error_messages = '<ol>';
        foreach ($error as $value) {
            $error_messages .= '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
        }
        $error_messages .= '</ol>';
    }

    $html  = '<div class="form-group'.(($error) ? ' has-error' : '').'">';
    $html .= $label;
    $html .= $input;
    $html .= (($error_messages) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error_messages.'</div>' : '');
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure Input::old() is empty, or is it not showing in the form input where you want it?

Comment: checked it with var_dump/dd, it is empty

Comment: it is ok before the redirect, but empty after the redirect

Comment: it's strange, because the withError() function works correctly

Comment: i also tried with Input::flash(), same result

Comment: Can you show the `bsInput` macro please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the issue: There was a leading space in the routes.php file, before the `<?php` opening tag. (was working on a team and someone else added that space).

Comment: How was this affecting the old input

Comment: old input uses session for storage, and that leading space (before the php tag) was output interfering with session (headers already sent by error)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Laravel 4 source:

```
/**
 * Flash an array of input to the session.
 *
 * @param  array  $input
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function withInput(array $input = null)
{
    $input = $input ?: $this->request->input();

    $this->session->flashInput($input);

    return $this;
}
```

It looks like if you don't pass an array of Input with ->withInput it tries to pull it from the original request. Try modifying the line like so:

```
        if ($event_add === true)
        {
            return Redirect::to('admin/event/create')
                       ->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());

        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('admin/event/edit/'.$event->event_id)
                        ->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());
        }
```

This should hopefully force it to pass the array of input values, instead of relying on the

```
        '$this->request->input()'
```

still existing in the session.

Comment: This was an interesting path to take on, but it still doesn't work. Flash data is still lost.

Comment: Very strange. Were you able to verify that the Input:all() or w/e you passed through had the values you wanted?

Comment: Also, have you tried just storing the data in a session manually, and retrieving it from the session from the view?

Comment: The Input::all() contains data before the redirect, only flash data is lost (any flash data, not just the input).
Also tried to store data in session, but that is working normally.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `Input::flash()` and then `withInput()`, which effectively does `Input::flash()` twice, probably invalidating the flashed input. Try only doing one of the two.

Also, `MihirEvent::save();` is wrong, you want to do `$event->save();`.

Comment: Then I suggest you try to recreate the issue in a blank new project using as little code as possible.

Comment: I will try that later.

Comment: it works with a new laravel installation, but i still can't figure out why this isn't working with this controller (the rest of the controllers are working well)